# Transactions vs Messages

Tags: transaction, iota-network, tangle

I'm reading the IOTA documentation, but I'm still having a doubt: is the Tangle a graph where each vertex is a transaction or is each vertex a message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess depends on the documentation you are reading. [Last version](https://wiki.iota.org/learn/about-iota/messages) of official wiki states the following:

> A **message** is an object that nodes gossip around in the network. It
> always references one to eight other messages, which are known as
> parents. **It is stored as a vertex on the Tangle data structure
> maintained by the nodes.**
>
> ...
>
> Previously, the **IOTA protocol used transactions (which were vertices
> in the Tangle)**, **where each transaction defined either an input or an
> output**. A grouping of those input/output transaction vertices made up
> a bundle that transferred the given values as an atomic unit. But this
> approach was seen as too time-consuming. So, we adopted a new
> transaction structure called the unspent transaction outputs (UTXO).

Also, it should be noted that there are different types of message payloads and one of them is called: [Transaction payload](https://wiki.iota.org/learn/about-iota/messages#transaction-payload).

Additionally, from the [Tangle section of the wiki.](https://wiki.iota.org/learn/about-iota/tangle#the-tangle-1)

> **The Tangle is a network of parallel processed messages**. These parallel
> messages form the "front" of the Tangle and offer multiple points for
> newly issued messages to attach to. There are no block producers, and
> it is enough to issue your transaction to any node so it would wrap it
> into a message and attach it to the Tangle.
>
> IOTA is a leaderless protocol. Multiple nodes attach multiple
> transaction messages to multiple points of the Tangle at the same
> time. IOTA has no bottlenecks, no middlemen, and no fees.

Finally, take a loot at the [Generalization of the Tangle transaction concept TIP](https://github.com/iotaledger/tips/blob/main/tips/TIP-0006/tip-0006.md), which states:

> The Tangle is the graph data structure behind IOTA. **In the current
> IOTA protocol, the vertices of the Tangle are represented by
> transactions. This document proposes an abstraction of this idea where
> the vertices are generalized messages, which then contain the
> transactions or other structures that are processed by the IOTA
> protocol.** Just as before, each message directly approves other
> messages, which are known as parents.
>
> The messages can contain payloads. These are core payloads that will
> be processed by all nodes as part of the IOTA protocol. Some payloads
> may have other nested payloads embedded inside. Hence, parsing is done
> layer by layer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!